# Could the Lifeblood/Abyss entity have been made by the ancient civilisation?

Tags: hollow-knight

The void tendrils, which are believed to be made by the ancient kingdom using void, have extremely similar eyes to the abyss entity. From a lore standpoint, is there anything contradicting this?

Comment: Welcome to Arqade! This question is quite borderline, because if nobody can prove that your theory is wrong it's no more than a speculation, therefore off topic here.

Comment: A visual comparison would also help your question.